# Hangman game using classes, cannot get it to work

Tags: c++, function, class, callback, subclass

So I have to make a Hangman game using classes and separate functions,the way I thought I could make it that would be easier was to make functions for each live left, but it doesn't print it when I call it...
Maybe any one can help me with this.
Thank you.

```
This is the main

// TheHangmanGame.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DrawHangman.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << "WHY wont u WORK!!!! \n" ;
    cout << "asdf" << &DrawHangman::setDrawMan0 <<  "\n" ;
    cout << "work \n"; 
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

//--------------------------------------------

```
//header file

#ifndef DRAWHANGMAN_H
#define DRAWHANGMAN_H
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class DrawHangman
{
public: 
    DrawHangman(char);


void setDrawMan0(char);
int getDrawMan0();
void setDrawMan1(char);
int getDrawMan1();
void setDrawMan2(char);
int getDrawMan2();
void setDrawMan3(char);
int getDrawMan3();
void setDrawMan4(char);
int getDrawMan4();
void setDrawMan5(char);
int getDrawMan5();
void setDrawMan6(char);
int getDrawMan6();
};
#endif
```

//-------------------------------

```
//cpp file
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DrawHangman.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

DrawHangman::DrawHangman(char)
{
}

void DrawHangman::setDrawMan0(char)
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "_______" << endl;
    cout << "|     |" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
}
int DrawHangman::getDrawMan0()
{
    return 1;
}
void DrawHangman::setDrawMan1(char)
{
    cout << "_______" << endl;
    cout << "|     |" << endl;
    cout << "|     o" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
}
void DrawHangman::setDrawMan2(char)
{
    cout << "_______" << endl;
    cout << "|     |" << endl;
    cout << "|     o" << endl;
    cout << "|    /" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
}
void DrawHangman::setDrawMan3(char)
{
    cout << "_______" << endl;
    cout << "|     |" << endl;
    cout << "|     o" << endl;
    cout << "|    /|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
}
void DrawHangman::setDrawMan4(char)
{
    cout << "_______" << endl;
    cout << "|     |" << endl;
    cout << "|     o" << endl;
    cout << "|    /|\\" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
}
void DrawHangman::setDrawMan5(char)
{
    cout << "_______" << endl;
    cout << "|     |" << endl;
    cout << "|     o" << endl;
    cout << "|    /|\\" << endl;
    cout << "|    /" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
}
void DrawHangman::setDrawMan6(char)
{
    cout << "_______" << endl;
    cout << "|     |" << endl;
    cout << "|     o" << endl;
    cout << "|    /|\\" << endl;
    cout << "|    / \\" << endl;
    cout << "|" << endl;
}
```

Comment: I dont think `cout << "asdf" << &DrawHangman::setDrawMan0 <<  "\n" ;` does what you think it does.

Comment: k i changed it but it returns 1 since i put return 1, how can i get it to print out what's written...

Comment: You need to go over your OOP basics. a) you're not actually calling the function (Hint: it's missing `()` and you shouldn't have `&` at the beginning), b) `DrawHangman::` is also wrong, I'll leave it up to you to find out why.

Comment: Please do not just pick tags at random - your question has nothing to do with callbacks or subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

&DrawHangman::setDrawMan0 does not call the function, it returns a pointer to a member. The problem is that the setDrawManX() functions are not static.

You can either make them static or you can create an instance of DrawHangman on which to call the instance methods.

Also, why do you have two overloads of each function? I cant see any reason for the unnamed char parameter.

Comment: I don't see any overloads in the OP's code. There are however a number of unused (and mostly undefined) functions starting with `get`.

Comment: You're right. I misread the get...() and set...() methods as having the same name.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot wrong with your code. For a start, it has a bad design - one of the main purposes of functions is for code reuse and to [avoid repeating yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), but each of your `set` functions is duplicating the work of the previous one.

That aside, here are the fixes you need to get your code working (and tidy it up a little):

- Get rid of `#include <ctime>` - you are not using this header.
- Get rid of `#include <string>` - you are not using this header.
- In `.cpp` files where you have `using namespace std` at the top, do not repeat it inside functions.
- It is bad practice to use `using namespace std` inside header files as this pollutes all enclosing namespaces of files which include your header. In any case, you are not using any members of the `std` namespace in your header file, so it is pointless.
- Get rid of `&` before your function call - that operator returns the address of the function, which is not what you want.
- Call your functions correctly. For functions with no parameters, that means placing empty parentheses after the function name e.g. `setDrawMan0()` and for functions with parameters and no default values, provide an argument e.g. `setDrawMan0(1)`.
- Do not provide parameters to functions which you do not use. You are not using a `char` parameter in your `setDrawMan` functions. Instead, define the function as `setDrawMan()` (i.e. with no parameters).
- Your `getDrawMan` functions appear to have no use, and you haven't even defined most of them. Delete them or give them a purpose.
- If you have a function which returns `void`, then there is no point in streaming it to `cout`. Your `setDrawMan` functions themselves stream to `cout`, so just call the function by itself e.g. `setDrawMan0()` (but see next point).
- Your `setDrawMan` functions do not access any member variables, so declare them as `static`. In fact, you are not really using classes in any meaningful way here - all you are doing is collecting a group of related functions together. This can also be achieved by having them as free functions declared inside a namespace.
- If you really want to use classes (and it seems like your assignment requires that), then you are going about it the wrong way. Instead of having a bunch of different hard coded draw functions, have a class which keeps track of how many lives are left in a member variable. Then have a single draw function which checks the number of lives and draws accordingly.

Comment: Finally an answer that covers everything. +1 for having the patience I did not.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't it be better to call the "setDrawMan" as a standard c function instead of trying to overload the cout?

Instead of

```
.h
void setDrawMan0(char);

main
cout << "asdf" << &DrawHangman::setDrawMan0 <<  "\n" ;
```

Type

```
.h
void setDrawMan0(void);

main
cout << "asdf" << DrawHangman::setDrawMan0() <<  "\n" ;
```

This way, it is simpler to interpret the code and predict it's behaviour.

Comment: When removing "&" I get this error 'DrawHangman::setDrawMan0': function call missing argument list; use '&DrawHangman::setDrawMan0' to create a pointer to member

Comment: -1: Your answer refers to C when the question is about C++, your code samples are not valid C or C++, and I can't even understand the point you're trying to make here. All you appear to have done is changed the OP's unused `char` parameter to `void`, and fixed some syntax errors - so what do you mean by overloading cout and "simpler to interpret the code and predict its behaviour"?